# postgresql error User "redacted_user" has no password assigned. NOT USING DOCKER

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-22.04

So I'm editing my original post and reducing it a bit.

I have a server running Ubuntu 22.04LTS and postgresql 10. I have installed an application on it that requires access to the dbase via it's own dbase user, password and the dbase "gitea".

I created a user "gitea" with a password in postrgesql and I can access it locally using the following command:

```
psql gitea gitea
```

My pg_hba.conf file is:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             bugs            127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 md5
host    all             gitea           127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 md5

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

So why does this allow me to access the dbase without a password? Is it an easy change to make sure that the user "gitea" always has to use a password whether it's local or remote?

Cheers!!

Comment: If you have two questions, you should ask two questions.  The error giving in your title is not the error given in the body, so it is hard to figure out what the two questions even are.

Comment: Your first command is not evidence that you have a password assigned.  Since it accesses the database via the 'trust' entry, no password is required.

Comment: jjanes, point well taken. I have tried to change the gitea line in the pg_hba.conf fie to "ost    all             gitea           127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 password
but this made no difference. on that machine I could still login with no password.

Comment: What is `listen_addresses` set to in `postgresql.conf`? See [Connection settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html).  I am betting it is set to `localhost` and therefore  only listening on `127.0.0.1/32`  and `::1/128` not to `192.168.101.32` that `europa` is mapped to.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your response, it is indeed set top localhost. Now normally the dbase will be accessed via a web server on the same server so localhost should suffice correct? It's just my actual test would be invalid I guess? Anyways, I've re-written my post to simplify my questions.

Comment: Your psql command is using the unix-domain socket, so the "host" lines of pg_hba doesn't matter, only the "local" line.  Change that from trust to md5 or "scram-sha-256".

Comment: In addition to @jjanes comments I would spend time here [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: jjanes & Adrian, so no joy changing the METHOD to either settings and yes, I'm restarting postgresql in between changes. I guess Adrian's suggestion is best, I'll have to spend time that the "gitea" people didn't spend on setting up dbases for their application. That's what happens when it's free I guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Looks to me the `gitea` folks did spend the time [Postgres database prep](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/database-prep/#postgresql).  2) To your question add the changes you made and the errors you got.